# Having trouble with 2d projection (Opengl)

Tags: opengl, c++, glfw

I need to change the normalize coords from -1 to 1 to the width and height of my application. The reason why I want to change the normalize coords is because i think it would be a easier set position of objects and find the globalbounds of objects

my Rectangle disappear when i put my projection matrix in the vertex shader

Vertex shader code

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
uniform vec2 offset;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
 vec4 translate = vec4(offset.x, offset.y, 0.0, 0.0); //Using translate to move the rectangle via 
                                                      //gluniform2f
 gl_Position = projection * position + translate;
} 

glm::mat4 proj = glm::ortho(-2.f, 2.f, -1.5f, 1.5f, -1.f, 1.f);
shader.setMat4("proj", proj);
```

Comment: There's no matrix named "proj" in your shader. On the cpu side, in the setMat4() function call, change the first argument "proj" to "projection".

Comment: @Daniel_1985 thankyou so much

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @Daniel_1985 yes it did but i notice my rectangle is still has a -1 to 1 position even its drawing it as my height and width of my application

Comment: @Daniel_1985 .What im basically trying to ask does the projection actually changes the normalize coords or just manipulates the ortho to fit the -1 to 1 coords

Comment: You're correct on that the projection manipulates the ortho to fit the (-1 to1) coords. The glm::ortho() function basically creates an orthographic transformation matrix that transforms vertices from view/camera space into clip space (-1 to 1).

Comment: You can learn more about the various transformation stages here: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems